# Novel with teleportation and a progress-delaying bureaucrat?

Tags: story-identification, novel, teleportation

A decade or more ago, I read a novel in which a bureaucrat (sorta), whose main responsibility was to prevent change from happening too rapidly, ends up trying to prevent all teleportation from failing.  It's so common, people live in high-rises with no doors, so the death toll would be immense.  He eventually learns that living stars are having their energy sucked away by the teleportation.

I liked the character, but I don't remember his name or the name of the novel.

Answer (score 10):

Frank Herbert's *[Whipping Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipping_Star)*, published 1970.

From Wikipedia:

> After suffering under a tyrannous pure democracy which had the power
>   to create laws so fast that no thought could be given to the effects,
>   the sentients of the galaxy found the need for a Bureau of Sabotage
>   (BuSab) to slow the wheels of government, thereby preventing it from
>   legislating recklessly.
>
> Jorj X. McKie is a saboteur extraordinary, a born troublemaker who
>   has naturally become one of BuSab's best agents. As the novel opens,
>   it is revealed that Calebans, who are beings visible to other sentient
>   species as stars, have been disappearing one by one. Each
>   disappearance is accompanied by millions of sentient deaths and
>   instances of incurable insanity.

[image]

Comment: That's it!  Funny, I don't remember it as being like something Frank Herbert would have written.  I'll definitely look it up.

Comment: And, THANK YOU.  I hit return, and it posted before I could say that.

Comment: In my opinion, the sequel, *The Dosadi Experiment* is Herbert's best novel, bar none.