# Looking for a title of a sci-fi novel or story where a government department's job was to slow things down

Tags: story-identification, government

I read a sci-fi novel or novella about a man that worked for a government department whose job it was to slow things down so the people didn't get run over by the government. Any ideas of the title? I think there was a lot of subterfuge between the agents. It's on the edge of my memory.

Comment: What were the sci-fi elements of this novel? When did you read it? How old was it? Was it in English? Where/when was it set? Anything about the plot? *Any* more details you can remember might help someone to identify it!

Comment: Like Frank Herbert's "Bureau of Sabotage" stories? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureau_of_Sabotage

Comment: Certainly not the answer, or even directly related, but the description here reminded me of Jack Vance's short "Dodkin's Job".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might this be one of the stories set in Frank Herbert's fictional universe featuring a Bureau of Sabotage? From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureau_of_Sabotage) on them:

> In Herbert's fiction, sometime in the far future, government becomes
> terrifyingly efficient. Red tape no longer exists: laws are conceived
> of, passed, funded, and executed within hours, rather than months. **The
> bureaucratic machinery becomes a juggernaut, rolling over human
> concerns and welfare with terrible speed**...

There are two novels (*[Whipping Star](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2257)*, first serialized in *Worlds of If* in 1970, and *[The Dosadi Experiment](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2258)*, serialized in *Galaxy* in 1977), or it might be the short story introducing the concept: "[The Tactful Saboteur](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57210)."

*Whipping Star* has come up here before, and it was unofficially accepted (via comment) as the answer for a somewhat similar question. See: [Novel with teleportation and a progress-delaying bureaucrat?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73678/novel-with-teleportation-and-a-progress-delaying-bureaucrat)

Comment: The Tactful Sabatoeur. Thanks so much!

Comment: Now I just have to look through a few hundred anthologies in the garage to find it :)